# Compilar e Rodar GUI no Android

Tags: android, c, gtk

Uso o c4droid para compilar codigos em C usando o gcc, nos meus estudos quero adentrar na interface grafica, porem como estou sem computador pensei em usar no proprio android. Pois bem, instalei o app GNU Root Debian, instalei o gtk3, glade e suas dependencias. No app Debian, consiguo compilar o codigo, mas na hora de executar com ./ aparece o erro da foto anexada aqui. Ja pesquisei mas de nenhuma forma consegui resolver este erro, minha duvida e, sera que esse erro esta acontecendo por nao ser possivel abrir uma interface grafica no android? Alguem ja tentou algo parecido? Fico no aguardo[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Creio não ser possível pois o próprio Android já está executando um X Server que está apontando pra tela do seu smartphone. Esta hipótese é corroborada pela mensagem de erro de que o display 1 não pode ser aberto.

Comment: Obrigado pelo contato! Eu nao poderia usar um app VNC para se conectar ao Debian? Se pudesse, ele entraria em conflito com o XServer? Em pesquisas vi que poderia ser usado outro server, como por exemplo Xclock, isso procede?

Comment: Pode usar um app VNC, mas o XServer tem que ser executado no Debian para o VNC poder ter o que exibir. XClock não é um servidor X, mas sim uma aplicação muito básica que pode ser executada em um ambiente gráfico. Acredito que você irá precisar de um computador mesmo...

Comment: Fpolina, ja baixei o vnc4server no Debian e um cliente no android. Consegui conectar com localhost na porta 5901, mas no cliente vnc aparece apenas uma tela cinza sem aspecto. Bom, nao tera como fugir do computador, mas seria uma mao na roda poder programar gui pelo proprio android. Vou tentar, talvez no futuro essa opcao ja tenha, mas o c4droid tem suporte ao qt com c++, em breve usarei ele, obrigado!

Comment: Se a resposta for satisfatória, aceite-a para fechar esta questão =)